# AWS Lambda static website with css or js files WITHOUT Hosting Static Files in s3 Bucket

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been trying to set up a static website on my lambda.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import sys
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"), encoding="utf8"))
    my_name = False
    if event["queryStringParameters"] and "my_name" in event["queryStringParameters"]:
        my_name_query = event["queryStringParameters"]["my_name"]
    template = env.get_template("index.html")
    html = template.render(
        my_name=my_name_query
    )
    return response(html)
def response(myhtml):
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": myhtml,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "text/html",
        }
    }
```

The HTML Template has a style tag that does not render:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css" >
```

I see alot of people posting about how I should host the CSS and JS files in S3, but to be honest it is MUCH more time-efficient to build this small web app using just Lambda.

With lambda and Cloud9 I can quickly modify the CSS and JS files. If I were looking to build an enterprise application, I would take the s3 approach, but this is a very small project.

Is there a way for me to render the CSS in this subdirectory of lambda?

Comment: How do you expect it to work? Lambda lasts only for max 15 minutes. And if you must run any backend code to make your website even show up, then its not static to begin with. Its dynamic.

Comment: @Marcin I expect the API Gateway Request to pull the HTML with the appropriate CSS and JS Scripts.

Comment: @MatthewMetros "Pull" the files from where? The same Lambda function? An Amazon S3 bucket?

Comment: Perhaps you could expand the linked-to CSS inside your HTML body response (replace the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css">` with the actual content of styles.css, or, if you prefer not to do that, investigate creating an additional Lambda function that handles the static route requests and have it serve up the static file content (you're basically emulating a mini web server at this point).

Comment: Or point it to static files in an S3 bucket, using a full path rather than a relative path.

Comment: you have to define a specific integration response : 
   "text/css" = <<-EOF
      #set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
      #set($context.responseOverride.status=$inputRoot.statusCode)
      #set($context.responseOverride.header=$inputRoot.headers)
      $inputRoot.body
    EOF